How to create a poll on Facebook page?
Facebook interface and features is an ever-changing moving target, so I should have my question qualified first: This question is about web version of the Facebook, released on 2024/07/06
I can easily create a Poll in the Facebook Groups:

but not on my personal Facebook Profile:

nor on the business Facebook Page I am an admin of:

It also does not let me Add [Poll] to your post later using ... menu:

Is there any way to create a Poll on Pages or Profiles?
Maybe ability to create Polls depends on some configuration/setup parameter which needs to be enabled in Page setup? If I recall correctly such option (to enable or disable Polls) exist for Groups
